# I am no able to install any package of openstack due to dpkg error, what should i do?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 41363 package 'openstack-dashboard':
 'Depends' field, missing architecture name, or garbage where architecture name expected
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)


Status of /var/lib/dpkg/status

Package: openstack-dashboard
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: extra
Section: net
Installed-Size: 15121
Maintainer: Chuck Short <zulcss@ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: horizon
Version: 1:2014.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0
Config-Version: 1:2014.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0
Depends: adduser, apache2 | httpd, libapache2-mod-wsgi (>= 2.3), python-django-horizon (= 1:2014.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0), python: (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There *might* be an error in the package itself, but that's unlikely.

Uninstall and purge the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openstack-dashboard
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get check
```

Then try installing again via

```
sudo apt-get install openstack-dashboard
```

Comment: If it still doesn't work, file a bug with the package management team.  I've only ever had 1 broken package *ever* in the standard repositories...

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openstack-dashboard : Depends: python: (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Have you tried following http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa already?

Comment: Yes Mr. Fabby, i tried your suggeted link but still i could not install any packages and it is showing the same error.

Comment: But now you have a different error (python dependency) Can you post the output of `'apt-get -f install` in the comments?

Comment: Output is: Reading package lists... Done; Building dependency tree      Reading state information... Done; Correcting dependencies... Done; The following extra packages will be installed:
openstack-dashboard python-django-horizon
Recommended packages: openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
The following packages will be upgraded:openstack-dashboard python-django-horizon
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1508 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,674 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

Comment: When i pressed Y, the output is :dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 41363 package 'openstack-dashboard':
 'Depends' field, missing architecture name, or garbage where architecture name expected
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: 1508 not upgraded????  Wow!  What does `lsb_release --release` say?

Comment: Output of lsb_release --release= Release: 14.04
You have new mail in /var/mail/root

Comment: Your problem is not the openstack-dashboard but your repository itself: 1508 non-upgraded packages.  First get rid of those and then try to install openstack again.